# SATA Hard Drives in won't format in Raid / Disappear sometimes

Tags: 12.04, drivers, sata

I am trying to setup a new computer with a software raid0.  I am running 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04.  I have my OS installed on a PATA Hard Drive, and 4 SATA 2TB Hitachi Drives to be raided.  The Motherboard is an ASUS M2N-L, which uses nForce 570 SLI / NVIDIA MCP55 (rev a3) for it's on-board SATA controller.  Im aware software raid may not be the best, but I have several other machines with this setup that work excellent for my purposes.

I was able to successfully build and start the raid via the Ubuntu GUI Disk Utility, but it gave me an error, that the partition was offset would run very slow and suggested I should re-partiton.  I did re-partition, but that simply resulted in more errors... cannot find device, or offset problems, eventually I came back around to the partitioning  step and I was able to mount the drive despite the error message, but it was indeed slow. And continuously failed to capture DV Video. ( The other raids like this in my office capture 8 streams at a time )

I have since swapped all 4 SATA cables, swapped the ports used and swapped the Motherboard itself ( I have 2 of this ASUS M2N-L ).  I have also swapped 1 of 4 2Tb Hard Drives. ( I have 6, will eventually have 8 in two 4 drive Raid0's in this box ) I have the BIOS updated to most recent.  I have tried manually using mdadm to asseble and create a raid array, but they always fail to format a filesystem.  The GUI sometimes will let me try and mount, but it always came back with errors like, look in "dmesg | tail". Bad superblock ... I looked this up and I tried to "repair" from an alternate superblock, but that also failed.

Additionally through out this process I've been checking back to the Disk Utility GUI and found that occasionally 1 of the 4 drives will disappear, or one of them will loose SMART DATA status.  If I restart, all drives and all SMART DATA return. ( Boot shows all drives, all with SMART )

In my mind all the observations point to a driver conflict with Ubuntu, but I didn't find anyone else complaining of issues with my combination of hardware?  ASUS has "Linux Drivers" but none for any Debian based liunx, I tried converting rpms and installing, but that either didn't work or had no effect ( is it the same driver already included with Ubuntu? )

Any ideas whats to blame or how to fix it?  I'll be happy to post any specific data, just ask, Im not sure whats relevant at this point... thanks in advance.  -Mark

1st Edit:
OK, attempting to re-create original error message that created a working raid, but was too slow.  In order to do that, Im trying to delete the partitions on each drive and I get this error:

```
Error erasing: helper exited with exit code 1: In part_del_partition:    
device_file=/dev/sde, offset=17408
Entering MS-DOS parser (offset=0, size=2000398934016)
MSDOS_MAGIC found
found partition type 0xee => protective MBR for GPT
Exiting MS-DOS parser
Entering EFI GPT parser
GPT magic found
partition_entry_lba=2
num_entries=128
size_of_entry=128
Leaving EFI GPT parser
EFI GPT partition table detected
got it
got disk
got partition - part->type=0
committed to disk
Error calling fsync(2) on /dev/sde: Input/output error
Cannot scrub filesystem signatures at offset=17408 and size=2000398899712
```

Attempting to delete another partition:

```
Error erasing: helper exited with exit code 1: In part_del_partition:     
device_file=/dev/sdb, offset=17408
Entering MS-DOS parser (offset=0, size=2000398934016)
MSDOS_MAGIC found
found partition type 0xee => protective MBR for GPT
Exiting MS-DOS parser
Entering EFI GPT parser
GPT magic found
partition_entry_lba=2
num_entries=128
size_of_entry=128
read failed (Input/output error)
Leaving EFI GPT parser
EFI GPT partition table detected
got it
Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
ped_disk_new() failed
```

Right after this error I tried:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [i686-linux-3.2.0-32-generic-pae] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net
Vendor:               /3:0:0:0
Product:              
User Capacity:        600,332,565,813,390,450 bytes [600 PB]
Logical block size:   774843950 bytes
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=47 offset=50 bd_len=46
>> Terminate command early due to bad response to IEC mode page
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T 
permissive' options.
```

1 of the 4 drives has now disappeared from my list in the Disk Utility GUI, and 2 of the 3 remaining no longer show SMART status, here is the only currently "available" SMART report:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdd
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [i686-linux-3.2.0-32-generic-pae] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi Deskstar 7K3000
Device Model:     Hitachi HDS723020BLA642
Serial Number:    <removed>
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 36ac60074
Firmware Version: MN6OA800
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Tue Nov 13 09:18:40 2012 CST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (19381) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 255) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED          
WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -              0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   135   135   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       84
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   182   182   024    Pre-fail  Always       -           276 (Average 353)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   135   135   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       26
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       197
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       23
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   150   150   000    Old_age   Always       -       40 (Min/Max 23/51)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   168   168   000    Old_age   Always       -       2323

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 2323 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 2323 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 197 hours (8 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      18:47:11.304  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      18:47:11.296  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  f5 00 00 01 00 00 e0 04      18:47:11.141  SECURITY FREEZE LOCK
  f5 00 00 01 00 00 e0 00      18:47:00.653  SECURITY FREEZE LOCK
  e3 00 00 01 00 00 a0 00      18:47:00.007  IDLE

Error 2322 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 197 hours (8 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      18:42:41.701  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      18:42:41.693  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      18:42:41.685  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      18:42:41.685  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      18:42:41.677  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 2321 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 182 hours (7 days + 14 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      03:48:06.464  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      03:48:06.464  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      03:48:06.464  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      03:48:06.456  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  f5 00 00 01 00 00 e0 04      03:48:06.301  SECURITY FREEZE LOCK

Error 2320 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 182 hours (7 days + 14 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 00 00 00 00

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      03:48:06.464  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      03:48:06.456  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  f5 00 00 01 00 00 e0 04      03:48:06.301  SECURITY FREEZE LOCK
  f5 00 00 01 00 00 e0 00      03:47:53.105  SECURITY FREEZE LOCK
  e3 00 00 01 00 00 a0 00      03:47:52.448  IDLE

Error 2319 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 182 hours (7 days + 14 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      03:46:21.429  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      03:46:21.421  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      03:46:21.413  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      03:46:21.413  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      03:46:21.405  IDENTIFY DEVICE

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I'll try and re-create that original error again... but as you can see I've seen many a error on this venture!  Thanks again!

2nd Edit:  I can't seem to get back to all empty hard drives in order to reproduce the original error!  1 of the 4 drives refuses to delete...

From the Disk Utility GUI

```
Error erasing: helper exited with exit code 1: In part_del_partition:     
device_file=/dev/sdd, offset=17408
Entering MS-DOS parser (offset=0, size=2000398934016)
MSDOS_MAGIC found
found partition type 0xee => protective MBR for GPT
Exiting MS-DOS parser
Entering EFI GPT parser
GPT magic found
partition_entry_lba=2
num_entries=128
size_of_entry=128
Leaving EFI GPT parser
EFI GPT partition table detected
got it
got disk
got partition - part->type=0
committed to disk
Error calling fsync(2) on /dev/sdd: Input/output error
Cannot scrub filesystem signatures at offset=17408 and size=2000398899712
```

I also tried wiping the drive with dd

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=1M
dd: writing `/dev/sdd': No space left on device
2009+0 records in
2008+0 records out
2106302464 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 1.73234 s, 1.2 GB/s
```

Seems odd that a 2TB drive is full after writing 1.2 GBs?  Since I can't seem to erase this drive I can't re-create my original error message... but something tells me that all these errors point to the same reason why I got an error in the first place.. if they point to anything at all.

3rd Edit:

dmesg output cropped due to askUbuntu character limit, full text available on Google Drive

https://docs.google.com/document/d/158e_I2h86wByzIgeOcOQ7VbL3CCJYqQus6bC8AfVcoI/edit

```
[  480.956838] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  480.956840] ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[  480.956842] ata5.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  480.956847] ata5.00: cmd 61/28:08:88:88:e0/00:00:e8:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 20480 out
[  480.956848]          res 51/84:08:00:08:00/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  480.956850] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  480.956852] ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[  480.956856] ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  480.956861] ata5.00: cmd 60/08:10:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 4096 in
[  480.956862]          res 51/84:08:00:08:00/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  480.956864] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  480.956866] ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[  480.956870] ata5: hard resetting link
[  480.956872] ata5: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
[  481.424020] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  481.448420] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  481.448427] ata5: EH complete
[  481.470607] ata5: EH in SWNCQ mode,QC:qc_active 0x7 sactive 0x7
[  481.470610] ata5: SWNCQ:qc_active 0x6 defer_bits 0x1 last_issue_tag 0x2
[  481.470611]   dhfis 0x6 dmafis 0x2 sdbfis 0x1
[  481.470613] ata5: ATA_REG 0x51 ERR_REG 0x84
[  481.470615] ata5: tag : dhfis dmafis sdbfis sactive
[  481.470617] ata5: tag 0x1: 1 1 0 1  
[  481.470619] ata5: tag 0x2: 1 0 0 1  
[  481.470625] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x7 SErr 0x400000 action 0x6 frozen
[  481.470627] ata5.00: Ata error. fis:0x21
[  481.470629] ata5: SError: { Handshk }
[  481.470632] ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  481.470636] ata5.00: cmd 60/08:00:00:01:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
[  481.470638]          res 51/84:28:00:00:00/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  481.470642] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  481.470644] ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[  481.470646] ata5.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  481.470650] ata5.00: cmd 61/28:08:88:88:e0/00:00:e8:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 20480 out
[  481.470651]          res 51/84:28:00:00:00/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  481.470654] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  481.470656] ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[  481.470658] ata5.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[  481.470662] ata5.00: cmd 61/28:10:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 20480 out
[  481.470663]          res 51/84:28:00:00:00/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  481.470665] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  481.470667] ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[  481.470671] ata5: hard resetting link
[  481.470672] ata5: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
[  481.936094] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  481.960135] ata5.00: model number mismatch 'Hitachi HDS723020BLA642' != 'tachi HDS723020BLA642                 \xffffff80\x10'
[  481.960139] ata5.00: revalidation failed (errno=-19)
[  481.960144] ata5.00: limiting speed to UDMA/133:PIO2
[  486.936020] ata5: hard resetting link
[  486.936024] ata5: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
[  487.404034] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  487.412144] ata5.00: n_sectors mismatch 3907029168 != 268435455
[  487.412148] ata5.00: old n_sectors matches native, probably late HPA lock, will try to unlock HPA
[  487.412151] ata5.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
[  487.412154] ata5.00: disabled
[  492.404029] ata5: hard resetting link
[  493.288057] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  493.296139] ata5.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
[  498.288135] ata5: hard resetting link
[  499.168100] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  499.176442] ata5.00: ATA-8: Hitachi HDS723020BLA642, MN6OA800, max UDMA/133
[  499.176445] ata5.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[  499.192263] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  499.192275] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  499.192279] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc]  Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor]
[  499.192283] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[  499.192284]         72 0b 47 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[  499.192292]         00 00 00 00 
[  499.192301] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc]  Add. Sense: Scsi parity error
[  499.192305] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 08 00
[  499.192313] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 256
[  499.192316] quiet_error: 57 callbacks suppressed
[  499.192318] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 32
[  499.192327] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192330] sd 4:0:0:0: killing request
[  499.192337] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  499.192340] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc]  Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor]
[  499.192343] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[  499.192346] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192350] 
[  499.192351]         72 0b 47 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[  499.192358]         00 00 00 00 
[  499.192361] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc]  Add. Sense: Scsi parity error
[  499.192364] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 e8 e0 88 88 00 00 28 00
[  499.192370] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3907029128
[  499.192372] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 488378641
[  499.192374] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc
[  499.192378] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 488378642
[  499.192380] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc
[  499.192382] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 488378643
[  499.192384] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc
[  499.192386] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 488378644
[  499.192388] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc
[  499.192391] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192394] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 488378645
[  499.192396] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192399] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc
[  499.192405] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  499.192408] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc]  Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor]
[  499.192411] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[  499.192412]         72 0b 47 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 
[  499.192419] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192421] 00 00 00 00 
[  499.192424] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192427]         00 00 00 00 
[  499.192430] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc]  Add. Sense: Scsi parity error
[  499.192433] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 00
[  499.192439] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[  499.192441] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 0
[  499.192442] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc
[  499.192447] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 1
[  499.192449] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc
[  499.192451] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 2
[  499.192453] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc
[  499.192466] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 3
[  499.192467] lost page write due to I/O error on sdc
[  499.192479] ata5: EH complete
[  499.192498] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192503] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192507] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192510] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY(16) failed
[  499.192512] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  499.192514] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[  499.192517] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192520] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192524] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192527] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY failed
[  499.192528] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  499.192531] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[  499.192536] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192542] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[  499.192548] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192553] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192557] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192561] sd 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  499.192564] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[  499.192566] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  499.192571] sdc: detected capacity change from 2000398934016 to 0
[  499.196063] ata5.00: detaching (SCSI 4:0:0:0)
[  499.196142] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[  499.196352] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Stopping disk
[  499.196989] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  499.196993] sdc: detected capacity change from 0 to 2000398934016
[  499.197053] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[  499.197080] Dev sdc: unable to read RDB block 0
[  499.197122]  sdc: unable to read partition table
[  499.871722] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Hitachi HDS72302 MN6O PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[  499.871907] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  499.871943] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[  499.871985] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  499.871988] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[  499.872013] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  501.738525]  sdc:
[  501.738749] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: Question is too vague to be answerable in its current form.  You will need to provide more details about the errors for help diagnosing them.

Comment: Added all the errors I can think of as relevant...

Comment: Much better.  How about any errors in `dmesg`?

Comment: `dmesg` posted!

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, I took the Hard drives from this unit and plugged them into one of my other Ubuntu boxes.  As I suspected the drives assembled into a raid and formatted to ext4 with the GUI just fine... I then plugged them back into the problem box and tried to capture.  It failed after about 10 seconds, and here is the dmesg report after that fail.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XmSOnlHToAzdWKNhEE2M6f9avGHka3-NImdxMs_ua0g/edit

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have either a bad sata cable, bad sata controller, or bad drive.  Try changing the cables first.  You don't have an old sandybridge system with the P68 chipset do you?  They had defective sata controllers and had to recall them.

Comment: Re: Cables
"I have since swapped all 4 SATA cables"

Re: Controller
"...and swapped the Motherboard itself ( I have 2 of this ASUS M2N-L )"  and no, not a P68, unless Im really wrong about something... "ASUS M2N-L, which uses nForce 570 SLI / NVIDIA MCP55 (rev a3) for it's on-board SATA controller"

Re: Drive
From my comments
"I took the Hard drives from this unit and plugged them into one of my other Ubuntu boxes ... formatted to ext4 with the GUI just fine"

Any other ideas? :-/

Comment: @starKast, are you sure you are using SATA-II cables?  Does the other box only support SATA-I?  Some drives have a jumper to limit them to SATA-I; you might try that.

Comment: After some digging, the SATA on ASUS M2N-L is SATA 2.  My Hitachi HDS723020BLA642 Drives are SATA 3.  So are you recommending trying SATA 2 cables then? or SATA 3 cables?  There are 2 pins on each pf my drives, but no jumper on them, and I haven't been able to figure out what it's for...

Comment: @starKast, does the other computer support SATA-III?  If so then the drives may have a defect that prevents them from working correctly at SATA-II speeds.

Comment: So, if there is a drive defect, you would surmise that if I install windows on this computer ( the one not working ) that it would have similar problems?  I think I might do that as a test, any other ideas to test this?

Comment: @starKast, yes.  Did you say the cables you are using are SATA-2?

Comment: I don't know which type of SATA they are. They don't say anything on them about I II or III "Serial ATA  E315781 AWM Style 2725 80c 30V VW-1"... basically cheap red ones with metal clips... however in my search to find out I found a pretty strong consensus from the internet that the cables being I II or III is purely marketing and there is absolutely no difference in spec.  http://www.overclock.net/t/1188422/difference-between-sata-ii-and-sata-iii-cables  If you know something different, or how to check...?

Comment: I've also now tried 3 different sets of cables in total! Im not sure when I'll get the opportunity to try windows on the box, but could this be related to the problem?  http://www.hgst.com/tech/techlib.nsf/techdocs/3D2E8D174ACEA749882577AE006F3F05/$file/AFtechbrief.pdf

Comment: @starKast, no, this is either a bad drive, bad controller, or bad cable.  If you have ruled out the cables, check if the other computer is running them at SATA-3 speed ( look in /var/log/kern.log ).  If it isn't then that rules out the drives.

Comment: hmmmm, looked in /var/log/kern.log in one of my other working 12.04 boxes and the same model drives running in there where the troubled ones worked are running at 3Gbs ( which means SATA II? ) which means it isn't the drives right?  So it must be the controller? Well I did the windowsXP test, and I got data loss errors there too... BUT I also plugged in 2 random other SATA drives I had around and tested them in 12.04 and they worked completely as expected, so ... it's the controller, but only with the drives I need it to work with!?! A co-worker found a bootable Hitachi Utility to try..